# Elementos depois do Seletor Hover

Tags: css

As vezes vejo alguns códigos css onde o seletor hover é utilizado da seguinte maneira. Algúem sabe como o  hover esta sendo aplicado desse jeito?

```
elemento li elemento img{
}

elemento li elemento:hover img{
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso, você está dizendo que ao passar o mouse no elemento, você quer que aplique o seu CSS no `img`

Comment: [:hover - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Answer (score 2):

No CSS o(s) elemento(s) a direita do seletor `:hover` são os que receberão a mudança de estilo.

Basicamente o [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) aplica estilo(s) a elemento(s) definido(s) por você quando o mouse está sobre elemento(s), no exemplo que você postou ao passar o mouse no **elemento pai da imagem** será aplicado um estilo na **imagem**.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
ul li div img{
}

ul li div:hover img{
  width: 120px;
}

img {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/fundo-lobo-uivando-na-lua_23-2147645253.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/lobo-que-urra-o-fundo_1355-15.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando o mouse passar por cima do "elemento" o estilo sera aplicado no "img", ou seja vamos supor que o elemento é uma div, ao passar o mouse na div a imagem que esta dentro da div vai receber aquele estilo.