# Imagem aparecer ao passar o mouse sobre texto

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Estou fazendo um site para uma pizzaria e preciso que, ao passar o mouse sobre o uma pizza do cardápio (texto) apareça ao lado uma imagem da pizza correspondente.

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre a utilização do hover? veja o link > https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246447/88202

Comment: coloque o código para podermos visualizar

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo utilizando somente `CSS`, deixei o código comentado para um melhor entendimento, segue abaixo o código e algumas referências:

[:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

[Combinador **~**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

[Propriedade display](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
/* Defino o tamanho de todas as imagens */
img { 
  width: 50px;
}

/* Oculto a imagem de id igual a "img2" */
#img2 {
    display: none;
}

/* Ao passar o mouse na img1 a img2 será exibida alinhada */
#img1:hover ~ #img2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="img1" src="https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/fundo-lobo-uivando-na-lua_23-2147645253.jpg" />

  <img id="img2" src="https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/lobo-que-urra-o-fundo_1355-15.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem `N` formas de se fazer isso, você pode usar só `CSS`, ou pode usar `JS`.

Um exemplo simples de se fazer usando `jQuery` é:

```js
$('ul li span').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).next().show()
})

$('ul li span').on('mouseout', function(){
  $(this).next().hide()
})
```

```css
ul li img{
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
}

ul li span{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Pizza 1</span>
    <img src="http://www.corpoealma.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/pizzabar.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Pizza 2</span>
    <img src="http://bhdicas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pizza-site-or.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```